# Identify the order of elements persisted in CoreData - ios - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, mapping, restkit

I am creating a response descriptor for json to core data mapping in RestkitManager. The parent object is "level" and it has an array of "sublevel" objects.

```
RKDynamicMapping *levelMapping = [Level map];
RKResponseDescriptor* levelRd = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:levelMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"entity/:entityId" keyPath:@"summary.levels" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[self.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:levelRd];
```

In Level class

```
+ (RKEntityMapping *)mapping {
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];

[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"id" : @"id",
                                              @"name" : @"name",
                                              @"state" : @"state"
                                              }];
[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"sublevel" toKeyPath:@"sublevelList" withMapping:[Sublevel map]]];
return mapping;
}
```

In Sublevel

```
+ (RKEntityMapping *)map {
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];

[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"id" : @"id",
                                              @"staticNode.obj.name" : @"name"
                                              }];
return mapping;
}
```

When I try to fetch **sublevel** on object **level**, I get it in random order. Sometimes 2nd sublevel get printed first. Is there any way to maintain the order?

As I understand, when mapping is done, I don't have any control over what is getting persisted in the database. Hence, I am not able to assign any order number myself. Apart from that, I have explored **metadata.routing.parameters** but for this I need to pass parameters in the API call itself - which is not desirable.

Any pointers on how to maintain the order would be helpful.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to maintain the order. What you can do is to set your fetch request's sort descriptor which will return the Sublevels in a particular specified order. Obviously this sort descriptor will have to based on one of your object's attributes. So either `id`, `name` or another attribute you add to specifically define an order.

Comment: Is it possible to intercept the mapping in any way and then persist the data of your own?